# Add a loading animation while the promise loads and displays the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I finished the functionality side of this simple app but now I want to add some good UX aswell so I want to add a loading animation (a spinner) while the JSON loads and before it displays the result of the promise, but I cannot seem to find a solution by googling.

Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/kresimircoko/pen/ZLJjVM.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
const API_KEY = '?api_key=625023d7336dd01a98098c0b68daab7e';
const root = 'https://www.warcraftlogs.com:443/v1/';
const zonesBtn = document.querySelector('#zones');
const responseList = document.querySelector('#response');
console.clear();

const requestJSON = objType => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            try {
                resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
            catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.open('GET', root + objType + API_KEY);
        xhr.send();
    });
};

function displayBosses(zoneID) {
    let bosses = document.querySelectorAll(`.bosses[data-zoneid="${zoneID}"]`);
    requestJSON('zones')
        .then(data => {
            let output = '';
            data.find(zone => 
                zone.id === parseInt(zoneID, 10)
            ).encounters.map(encounter => {
                output += `<li class="boss" data-zoneid="${zoneID}">${encounter.name}</li>`;
                bosses.forEach(boss => {
                    boss.innerHTML = output;
                });
            }).join('');
    });
}

function displayZones() {
    let output = '';
    requestJSON('zones')
        .then(zones => {
            return zones.map(zone => {
                output += `
                    <ul data-zoneid="${zone.id}" class="zones"> 
                        <span>${zone.name}</span>
                        <ul data-zoneid="${zone.id}" class="bosses"></ul>
                    </ul>`;
                response.innerHTML = output;
            }).join('');
        })
        .then(responseList.style.display = 'flex');
}

zonesBtn.addEventListener('click', displayZones);
responseList.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    const target = evt.target.parentElement;
    const zoneID = target.dataset.zoneid;
    displayBosses(zoneID);
    if (target.classList.contains('clicked'))
        target.classList.remove('clicked');
    else 
        target.classList.add('clicked')
});
```

Comment: Are you going to create the spinner yourself or is the question to direct you to a good spinner plugin/library/snippet? In a nutshell, you'll want to do a call to the function rendering the spinner just before or after you send the xhr call for the data, then as the data returns, remove the spinner. Worst case, just put a half-transparent grey overlay on top of your html, so the UI is (position absolute etc) kinda 'unusable, and change the cursor pointer into a default spinner with the css rule `cursor: wait;`

Comment: @Shilly I would create the spinner myself, I want to avoid libraries and external code, at least in this case. So what you're saying is that I should call the `spinner rendering function` in the first `.then` in the `displayZones` function? Feel free to correct me :)

Comment: No, before the first 'then', since the 'then' will resolve only when the data returns. So either add a callback parameter to your ajax call, or have the ajax call always show a spinner, or call it before you start the async requestJSON.then() You'll want to remove the spinner again in the first 'then'. A bit like: `function displayBosses(zoneID) { showSpinner(); requestJSON().then( hideSpinner(); data.find(.......`

Comment: @Shilly That sounds like it should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spinner is a FontAwesome icon wrapped in a `spinner` div for which we control the `display` property to show up when the button is clicked but hide when the `promise` has resolved.

```
function displayZones() {
    if (!this.classList.contains('open')) {
        spinner.style.display = 'block';
        this.classList.add('open');
    }
    let output = '';
    requestJSON('zones')
        .then(zones => {
            spinner.style.display = 'none';
            return zones.map(zone => {
                output += `
                    <ul data-zoneid="${zone.id}" class="zones"> 
                        <span>${zone.name}</span>
                        <ul data-zoneid="${zone.id}" class="bosses"></ul>
                    </ul>`;
                response.innerHTML = output;
            }).join('');
        })
        .then(responseList.style.display = 'flex');
}
```